# How do you remove only punctuation within words in a string?

Tags: swift, string, algorithm, range, character

PROBLEM:
Remove all punctuation inside words in a string, not outside like beginning and end of a string. (Ex. we'll = well, We're = Were, etc.)

WHAT I'VE TRIED (Works except I have to name every single kind of punctuation to remove individually.. bad solution):

**INPUT**:     `let testString = "What's with this project I'm trying to build, it's cra!zy!"`

```
if let resultRange = myString.range(of: "'") {
    let startIndex = resultRange.lowerBound
    let endIndex = resultRange.upperBound
    let range = startIndex..<endIndex
    let result = myString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: "")
    print(result) // outputs = "Whats with this project Im trying to build, its cra!zy"
}
```

ALSO TRIED (It's good, but it removes the punctuation from both the start and end of words, which fails the above requirements):

```
extension String {
  func removingCharacters(inCharacterSet forbiddenCharacters:CharacterSet) -> String
{
    var filteredString = self
    while true {
      if var forbiddenCharRange = filteredString.rangeOfCharacter(from: forbiddenCharacters)  {
        filteredString.removeSubrange(forbiddenCharRange)
      }
      else {
        break
      }
    }

    return filteredString
  }
}

var resultMyString = myString.removingCharacters(inCharacterSet: .punctuationCharacters)
print(resultMyString) // outputs = "Whats with this project Im trying to build its crazy"
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**: `"Whats with this project Im trying to build, its crazy!"`

Comment: It feels like regexp would be the perfect tool for this. Sadly don't know swift at all.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, wish I knew regex well enough to do this with regex.

Comment: Another way might be to look only for letters? Which characters to you allow exactly?

Comment: @Larme that's my first solution where I have to name every kind of punctuation, the CharacterSet has .punctuationCharacters which could remove all types but I need to restrict it to just inside words, not outside

Comment: Pattern could be improved, but `let pattern = "([^[:punct:]\\s])([[:punct:]])([^[:punct:]\\s])"` & `let quicklyStripped = str.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "$1$3", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: I put in your regex pattern like so:
.replacingOccurrences(of: "([^[:punct:]\\s])([[:punct:]])([^[:punct:]\\s])", with: "$1$3", options: .regularExpression)

It worked!  Thank you so much @Larme

Comment: Try this regex pattern: 
`(?<=\w)['!";:](?=\w)`
You can add any punctuation character inside `[]`.

there is another regex pattern but it is not accurate because it can match the `@` in something like: `blabla@blabla`

`(?<=\w)[^\w\s](?=\w)`


Live demo: 

`https://regex101.com/r/tVPmpF/1`

Comment: @SaSkY I'd love to try it out, but it throws invalid escape sequences in Swift, tried fixing it but I only know so much of Swift Regex.  Thanks.

Comment: It's because `\w` needs to be `\\w`

Comment: @Larme tried that but still throwing errors

Answer (score 1):

Regex that accounts for all valid types of punctuation in a regular expression = **[:punct:]**

Combine that regex to account for word boundaries = **"\b[:punct:]\b"**

```
let testString = "What's with this project I'm trying to build, it's cra!zy!"

let result = testString
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b[:punct:]\\b", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

**Outputs** = `"Whats with this project Im trying to build, its crazy!"`